# Failed to load resource under Chrome net::ERR_ADDRESS_IN_USE

Tags: chromium

When my application page is loaded, it takes this mistake

But when I'm refreshed, the page will be ok.

[image: screenshot]

Please help me analyze this mistake, which is the chrome error code? What is the cause of the mistake?

Comment: If you're on Windows, open the Event Viewer and check for the presence of events with source _Tcpip_ and event id 4227. It seems Chrome has been abusing the TCP/IP stack since version 67.

Comment: @bit2shift Can you point to any resources that describe more thoroughly what you've mentioned?

Comment: Although most of it is based on empirical evidence of my own, this [Google search](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22ERR_ADDRESS_IN_USE%22&lr=&hl=pt-PT&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A6%2F1%2F2018%2Ccd_max%3A8%2F16%2F2018&tbm=) shows other similar cases.